# Pivot disappears when refreshing data range

Tags: excel

I have a pivot that I am trying to update and refresh with new data, but when I update the range and refresh, it disappears entirely.  Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: Without more detail, nobody can offer much more advice than you'll find searching the internet. Are you hiding the data columns? Is the link still right? If you can reproduce your issue on a file that doesn't contain sensitive information, you might be more successful on an MS forum by sharing that.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please provide some context. Perhaps an image of the pivot before you refresh as well as the data. Then an image of the same range where you expect the pivot to be after the refresh (include the column and row headers). And an image of the refreshed data. That would be a good place to start.